# wildcard expansion in bash script

Tags: bash

if I write this string in my script:

```
list=$(ls /path/to/some/files/*/*/*.dat)
```

it works fine. But what I need is

```
files="files/*/*/*.dat"
list=$(ls /path/to/some/${files})
```

and it says

```
ls: /path/to/some/files/*/*/*.dat: No such file or directory
```

How should I do it?

Comment: works for me...only fails when there are no .dat files.

Comment: What are you going to do with `$list`? Parsing the output of `ls` is usually not the right approach.

Comment: I need to divide this list into several, N files in each, and then launch separate jobs with N input files per job on several computers in a cluster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
list=$(find /path/to/some/files/ -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -name '*.dat')
```

Comment: Using find is a good approach, but this will build a string of filenames which will break if they contain spaces.

Answer (score 19):

If you only get that message where there truly are no matching `.dat` files, add this to your script:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

It will cause the glob to expand to an empty list if there are no matching files, rather than being treated literally.